# Use PowerShell to Quickly Search Files for Regex and Output to CSV

Tags: regex, powershell

My goal is to search a directory recursively for all files that contain a regular expression with speed in mind. Then output to a CSV that has a column that includes the exact matches and another column shows the file they were found it. Thanks to the user woxxom, I've started playing with the `IO.File` as it's apparently much faster than using `Select-String`.

This is a project I've been working on for a long time and was able to accomplish via `Select-String` and using `Export-Csv`, but it's a rather slow process.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing with my new attempt?

```
$ResultsCSV = "C:\TEMP\Results.csv"
$Directory = "C:\TEMP\examples"
$RX = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.|dot|\[dot\]|\[\.\])){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
$TextFiles = Get-ChildItem $Directory -Include *.txt*,*.csv*,*.rtf*,*.eml*,*.msg*,*.dat*,*.ini*,*.mht* -Recurse
$out = [Text.StringBuilder]

foreach ($FileSearched in $TextFiles) {
    $text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($FileSearched)
    foreach ($match in ([regex]$RX).Matches($text)) {
        if (!(Test-Path $ResultsCSV)) {
            'Matches,File Path' | Out-File $ResultsCSV -Encoding ASCII
            $out.AppendLine('' + $match.value + ',' + $FileSearched.fullname)
            $match.value | Out-File $ResultsCSV -Encoding ascii -Append
            $FileSearched.Fullname | Out-File $ResultsCSV -Encoding ascii -Append
            $out.ToString() | Out-File $ResultsCSV -Encoding ascii -Append -NoNewline
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged excel?

Comment: Good call, I removed the tag.

Comment: *"Any thoughts on what I'm missing with my new attempt?"* Dunno. What doesn't work as expected?

Comment: It seems to identify the information, but when I attempt to write it to a file it only includes the last result. I thought I was iterating through all of the matches and appending, but it doesn't seem that way in the results.

Comment: Also, I'm failing to build my string that I want to write to the file. I can write each value to the file, but they end up in the same column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can speed performance by using Stream for Reading and writing

```
    $ResultsCSV = "C:\TEMP\Results.csv"
    $Directory = "C:\TEMP\examples"
    $RX = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.|dot|\[dot\]|\[\.\])){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"

    $TextFiles = Get-ChildItem $Directory -Include *.txt*,*.csv*,*.rtf*,*.eml*,*.msg*,*.dat*,*.ini*,*.mht* -Recurse

     $file2 =  new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($ResultsCSV) #output Stream
     $file2.WriteLine('Matches,File Path') # write header

    foreach ($FileSearched in $TextFiles) {   #loop over files in folder

        #    $text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($FileSearched)
        $file = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader ($FileSearched)  # Input Stream

        while ($text = $file.ReadLine()) {      # read line by line
            foreach ($match in ([regex]$RX).Matches($text)) {   
                   # write line to output stream
                   $file2.WriteLine("{0},{1}",$match.Value, $FileSearched.fullname )  
            } #foreach $match
        }#while $file
         $file.close();  
    } #foreach  
    $file2.close()
```

Comment: That did the trick, I cannot believe how fast this is. Thank you so very much for helping out with this!

Comment: One last question, if I wanted to append to an existing output file in the same format, could this easily be done?

Comment: You can append to an existing file if you don't want to create a new one. Modify the StreamWriter line to be:  $file2 =  new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($ResultsCSV,$true)  #Append or Create a new file Stream. $true means create new file if it's not exist.

Comment: I ran into one issue with using this approach. With .txt files, if there's a blank line, it will stop searching that file, so it misses anything after that. I've tried a few things, but cannot seem to get it to keep processing the file.

Comment: Replace the line of while to be:
while (($text = $file.ReadLine()) -ne $null ).

Comment: That did it! You make this stuff look easy. Thank you again!