# How do I Build a Regex Expression to Find String

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been studying content on the regex topic, but am having trouble understanding how to make it work! I need to build a regex to locate a particular string, potentially in multiple places throughout numerous log files. If I were keying the search expression into a text editor, it would look like this...

*Failed to Install*

Following is a typical example of a line containing the string I would like to search for (exit code # will vary)

!!!    Failed to install, with exit code 1603

I would really appreciate any help on how to build the regex for this. I suspect I might need the end of line character too?

I plan on using it in a variation of the script that was provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3142139/m-hassan in the following thread

[Use PowerShell to Quickly Search Files for Regex and Output to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983462/use-powershell-to-quickly-search-files-for-regex-and-output-to-csv)

I'm a newbie to powershell scripts, but I'd rather spend the time to figure this out, than pour over hundreds of log files!

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` retrieves file system items, `Import-Csv` imports CSV files, and `Select-String` performs regular expression pattern matching. What have you tried so far, and with what results?

Comment: Try `$s -match '(?<=Failed to install.*)\d+$'`

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck - You only require very simple regex for this. Assuming you want to capture the error code, this will work fine:

```
^.*Failed to install.*(exit code \d+)$
```

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/t8mkrb/2/)

If you don't care about the error code, and just want to know if it failed or not, you can honestly get away with something as simple as:

```
^.*Failed to install.*$
```

Hope this helps.